# Automated visual cues for being logged in to different machines?

Tags: ssh, terminal-emulator, cue, mnemonics

I often work with 3 machines at the same time, several sessions on X, several on Y, and Z is my local machine so obviously some sessions there - all sitting around in a terminal windows / tabs.

The thing is, I often confuse my local machine with some remote one, and this leads to amusing but occasionally somewhat tragic results.

I would like to have strong visual cues, which are triggered automatically by me logging in to a different machine, for which machine I am on, or at least cues which differ significantly for different machines.

So far I've been manually switching the color scheme for remote hosts (using Konsole), but that's: 1. manual and 2. doesn't distinguish between different hosts. And 1. manual, that's the most annoying part. If you forget to make this setting, you get a false sense of security.

**Notes:**

- I already have PS1 spelling out the hostname, I need something more eye-catching than that.
- Any reasonable heuristic for deciding when I've switchined hosts is fine, and you may assume I only use ssh if that helps.
- Solutions which also support SSHing-within-SSHing are quite welcome.
- I'm particularly (but not exclusively) interested in terminal emulator apps which let you control not just the backround as a solid color, but also have some image floating somewhere, or change the color of the session bar / window title bar, or other kinds of bells and whistles. Actually, something with actual bells and whistles would probably do the trick :-)

Comment: Adjusting the prompt (PS1) using colours and/or host specific strings in the .rc of the shell is the common way to avoid such disasters. Actually, it's not  ultimate safety either. Not su-ing to root anywhere but using own id's and starting everything sensitive via sudo, having DIFFERENT passwords on all hosts (it's a must anyway, isn't it?) would really stop you from starting sudo ugly_command on X while you wanted it to run on Y.

Comment: Also, echoing the right ansi color sequences (echo -e '...') in the .rc can set the background of the session. Just give this a try: echo -e "\e[44m"; clear Then see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

Comment: @GombaiSándor: I'm working as non-root everywhere anyway (most places I don't even have root access), so that's not much help. Coloring my prompt using escapess in PS1 might be useful I suppose. If you make an answer of it with an example you have an upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Terminix](https://github.com/gnunn1/terminix). It includes features such as, quoting their homepage: "Automatic (triggered) profile switches based on hostname and directory".

(Or iTerm2 if you're on Mac, however, you using Konsole at the moments suggests it's probably not the case.)

Answer (score 0):

My basic prompt:

```
$ echo $PS1
\u@\h\w\$
```

If I want the host to be green, I pick out the escape sequence of green from the ansi color list (**\e[32m**) and prepend the sequence of host (**\h**) with that and put the sequence of reset (**[0m**) so that other parts be with normal characters. Hence, my new PS1 is

```
export PS1='\u@\e[32m\h\e[0m\w\$ '
```

Putting it into my .bashrc would result in my choice of prompt at that host.

If I should want more, let's say my background to be cyan, then I would set the background sequence with an echo command and then just clear the screen:

```
echo -e '\e[46m'; clear
```